# python conditional issue (2.7)

Tags: if-statement, python-2.7

cccI have a python script that is driving me nuts. Here is the offending code... the code in the if statement is not running, can someone suggest why?:

```
print("refresh_type is: " + refresh_type)

if (refresh_type == "update"):
    print("hello world")
    cmd = 'sudo svn %s --username %s --password %s  %s' % ('up', un, pw, working_path)
    print("command is: " + str(cmd))
elif(refresh_type == 'checkout' or refresh_type == 'co'):
    cmd = 'sudo svn %s --username %s --password %s  %s %s' % (refreshType, un, pw, rc_service_url, working_path)

print('username = ' + credentials['un'])
print('password = ' + credentials['pw'])
print("working path = " + working_path)
```

Here are the outputs of the print statements:

```
refresh_type is: 'update'
username = 'cccc'
password = 'vvvvv'
working path = '/home/ubuntu/workingcopy/rc_service'
```

Comment: You can go a lot easier on the parenthesis there; `print` is *not* a function in python 2.7. What you you mean 'the if statement is not running'?

Comment: My one complaint with python so far is the lack of things delineating actions. I like putting the parenthesis there because it makes it immediately apparent what I am doing. Yes you don't need them but this to me is like drawing a box around it. I like it. I'll keep doing it.  I don't have a problem with end of line characters like semi-colons in other languages, nor with braces for functions. I like them too. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `refresh_type` value is *not* `update`, it's `'update'`. The rest of your variables suffer from the same ailment, they have quotes *as part of the string value*.

Use `print "refresh_type is:", repr(refresh_type)` as a diagnostic aid in this.

You could use:

```
if refresh_type == "'update'":
```

but you have a more fundamental problem, one where you end up with extra quotes in your string values.

To illustrate, a short Python interpreter session:

```
>>> print 'update'
update
>>> print "'update'"
'update'
>>> "'update'" == 'update'
False
>>> foo = "'update'"
>>> print repr(foo)
"'update'"
```

Comment: The repr(refresh_type) was a good tip. I was getting this value from a config file that had the refresh_type with quotes. Thanks.